# Print with toString() method

Tags: java, string, printing, tostring

```
class Box
{
// Instance Variables
double length ,ipsos ;
double width ,mikos ;
double height ,platos;
// Constructors
 public Box ( double side )
{
width = side ;
height = side ;
length = side ;
}
public Box ( double x , double y , double z)
{
    platos = y ;
ipsos = z;
mikos = x ;
}

// Methods
double calculate(double praksi)
{
return 2 * ( width * height +
width * length +
height * length ) ;
}
double volume(double emvadon)
{
return platos*ipsos*mikos ;
}

}
```

In the upper code, how can I make a toString() method, so I can return the values of volume and calculate ??? 
Im new with java so be as simple as you can please

Comment: If the exercise says **you** yould find the mistake, then **you** should do it. Also, try to use an IDE with autoformatting. It will help a lot.

Comment: toString() doesn't print anything, it just returns a String which is the representation of the Object

Comment: The method is used to get a String object representing the value of the Number Object.
If the method takes a primitive data type as an argument, then the String object representing the primitive data type value is return.
If the method takes two arguments, then a String representation of the first argument in the radix specified by the second argument will be returned.

Comment: Im studing alone and this exersise is hard for my level

Comment: as @MarcoAcierno said tostring doesnt print any thing ,its a method from String class

Comment: if u just want to print the result u cant print it in the main class or any method ,plz give us more details about the excersise

Comment: ok, i made it again more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print with toString() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598294/print-with-tostring-method)

Answer (score 0):

toString() is a method found on the Object.class, which all classes you write will extend automatically. Therefore your class will already have this method by default, but it won't return what you expect. You can override this method, and make it do exactly what you want to.

If you try and use your class, you'll find that toString() is already available:

```
new Box().toString();
```

Just write a new method for your class with the same signature and add your own code.

```
public String toString() {}
```