# Print with toString() method

Tags: java, string, methods, printing

```
class Box
{
    // Instance Variables
    double length ,ipsos ;
    double width ,mikos ;
    double height ,platos;
    // Constructors
    public Box ( double side )
    {
        width = side ;
        height = side ;
        length = side ;
    }
    public Box ( double x , double y , double z)
    {
        platos = y ;
        ipsos = z;
        mikos = x ;
    }

    // Methods
    double calculate(double praksi)
    {
        return 2 * ( width * height +
        width * length +
        height * length ) ;
    }
    double volume(double emvadon)
    {
        return platos*ipsos*mikos ;
    }

}
```

In the upper code, how can I make a toString() method, so I can return the values of volume and calculate ??? 
Im new with java so be as simple as you can please

Comment: `public String toString() {return "My String";}` ?

Comment: Check out this short [article on `toString()`, with an example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/209515-basics-of-tostring/).

Comment: will this return the values of volume and calculate??

Comment: Every class can override tostring. But you may not want to mix tostring with collateral effects. So create an attribute for the result, call the method that calculate and only after that call tostring

Comment: calculate and volume are methods

Comment: @NicolásCarlo Pedantic: Toss an `@Override` in there. `@Override public toString () { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your class (to override the `toString()` method):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Volume: " + volume(1) + "\n Calculate: " + calculate(1);
}
```

Note: `@Override` is optional: it's just communication and making sure you receive an error if you misspell the overridden method (`toString()`).

Also, why do you have parameters for `volume` and `calculate` if you don't use them? That's why I passed them a random number like `1` because it apparently doesn't matter what they are.

Comment: what should i do so this programm instead returning the values of volume or calculate will return it as string?

Comment: @user3217800 I'm not sure what you mean. This method does return the values as a string. Do you mean you want the other methods to return strings as well?

Comment: damn.. i misunderstood something. Can you please explain me what exackly return values as string means?

Comment: @user3217800 So when you return the values of `volume` and `calculate`, you are returning `double` values. You get that right? You are returning numerical values. An example is `return platos*ipsos*mikos ;` you are returning three things multiplied together. With the `toString()` method, you are returning those values, not as a `double`, but as a `String`. A string is just text. Example: `"Hello world!"` is a string. So let's say the value of `volume` was `10.5`, instead of returning that as a numerical value, you are returning it as a string value, perhaps `"Volume: 10.5"`.

Comment: nice, i got this. but in the upper code, we dont give values, so what will it print?

Comment: @user3217800 We do give values. `volume(1)` returns a value and `calculate(1)` returns a value. Then, with those values, we form a string: `"Volume: " + volume(1) + "\n Calculate: " + calculate(1);` and then just return that. It will print that.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what the parameters of the methods 'calculate', 'volme' are for?
If you're looking to override the default toString method, so when you call System.out.println(new Box(1,2,3)): it prints out the volume, and value calculate returns for the box then the following should work:

```
Box b = new Box(1,2,3);
System.out.println(b);
```

Then the following should work:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
  return "Volume: " + volume(0.0) + ", calculate: " + calculate(0.0);
}
```

This would print the volume and whatever calculate returns, both clearly labelled.

Comment: but why 0.0 in volume and calculate??

Comment: I couldn't work out what the arguments are meant to be, they appear to do nothing; so I just used some arbitrary values.